# Windows Messagebox didnt show and terminate in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am using `MessageBox` in C++, using the `winuser.h` header file.

When I run the application the message box doesn't show, and the program terminates on that line.

My code:

```
HWND hDlg=NULL;

MessageBox (hDlg, TEXT ("Check the UserName and Password is Correct"), TEXT ("Windows Logon"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

Note: I am also using `winwlx.h`. Would this cause a problem? How should I arrange the header files?

Comment: Are you sure that it terminates at that line?
Try to replace it with MessageBox(0,0,0,0);
Does result still the same?

Comment: Please show complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under normal conditions, `MessageBox()` will not crash the app.  The code you have shown is not passing any bad values to `MessageBox()`, so the only way it can crash is if your app's memory is badly corrupted from other code, or if there are external message/dialog hooks installed that are misbehaving.